# giving an element a temporary fixed width when using jQuery UI draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have some elements that have a relative width. however, when I drag one of these elements using the jquery UI's `draggable()` method, it shifts based on where I'd like to drag it. I tried the following code, attempting to use the start and stop callbacks:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id='item-list'>  
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#item-list {
  width: 40%;
}

#item-list li {
  width:  100%;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#item-list li").draggable({
  revert : true,
  helper : 'clone',
  start : function() {
    $(this).css('width',$(this).width());
  },
  stop : function() {
    $(this).css('width','100%');
  }
});
```

However, this only seems to work the second time I drag objects. is there some way to get this to work properly?

Answer (score 8):

Is that it? http://jsfiddle.net/CGQkB/

The trick is to address the of the `ui.helper` not just `$(this)` since that just points to the original `<li>` tag.

Comment: Dude.. I had to work with JqueryUI draggables today and for some reason nested elements weren't getting the proper sizes in chrome. Anyway this helped a lot thanks for posting it.

Comment: Happy to be of help. Cowabunga, dude ;)